# Installing the Pecl Oauth Module on MAMP OSX 10.6

Tags: php, oauth, mamp, pecl

Ok, so after a day of messing about with various things such as Fink, Macports, Pecl, etc. I have managed to install the oauth.so module on OSX.

However, I use MAMP locally, which I think uses its own version (i.e. in its own location) of PHP, and the module has installed to the main system version of PHP?

So I have run the version of PECL from the MAMP folders:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2/bin/pecl install oauth
```

But it seems to have installed it in the generic folder anyway

```
    ...
    Build process completed successfully
    Installing '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/oauth.so'
    install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/oauth-1.0.0
    configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
    You should add "extension=oauth.so" to php.ini
```

Note the /usr/lib/... folder.
But the php.ini MAMP is using, actually looks in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613

I thought it would be as easy as just copying the .so file over... but that was hoping for too much..

Can anyone help me, how can I install this extension in the correct folder and let php know about it??

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'm running MAMP Version 1.9.6 on Mac OSX Version 10.7.4 and had the same problem.

I checked my MAMP php error logs at `/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log`

and found this error

```
[22-Jul-2012 12:11:20] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/oauth.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/oauth.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/oauth.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
```

I fixed it with the following:

1. Download source from http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth

   Open up a terminal, navigate to where your downloaded file is and type the following commands:
2. `tar xzvf oauth-1.1.0.tgz`
3. `cd oauth-1.2.2/oauth-1.2.2`
4. `phpize`
5. `sudo ./configure MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7 CFLAGS="-arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp" CCFLAGS="-arch i386 -g -Os -pipe" CXXFLAGS="-arch i386 -g -Os -pipe" LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -bind_at_load"`

   **NOTE:** Make sure you type the right version number of your Mac OSX for the `TARGET` in the above command.
6. `sudo make`
7. `sudo make install`
8. `sudo cp /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/oauth.so /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/oauth.so`
9. In your favorite editor, open up `php.ini` (in my case its located at 
   `/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini`)
   and add the following line in the extensions area:

   `extension=oauth.so`
10. Save your changes and restart MAMP. You should see an oauth entry in the MAMP PHPINFO page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I wish I had found it earlier :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the php_ini setting of pecl to point to the php.ini of your MAMP installation. So:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2/bin/pecl config-set /Applications/MAMP/conf/php.ini
```

This should make pecl use your current MAMP php configuration

Comment: config-set expects 2 or 3 parameters??

Answer (score 0):

PECL Modules are compiled modules, in order to install them, you need the PHP headers. You can found the headers on php.net/downloads.php make sure you download a version which match with your PHP version. Then you can follow this : [Installing PHP OAuth in MAMP environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413380/installing-php-oauth-in-mamp-environment/24275145)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/bin/pear install HTTP_OAuth-0.3.2
```

use the above command to install Oauth libraries in MAMP

And then You should add "extension=oauth.so" to php.ini

Restart Server After Add extension in php.ini file