# Installing PHP OAuth in MAMP environment

Tags: php, oauth, mamp

I have tried following ALL tutorials out there on getting PHP OAuth extension installed under the MAMP environment, but can't get it to load for some reason.

I am using MAMP 1.9 with PHP 5.3.2

The most recent tutorial I was following was: http://lifeofadev.com/2011/03/09/mac-os-x-installing-oauth-so-into-xampp-mamp/

Does anyone else have experience with getting this to work?

Thanks!
Dennis

Comment: If you are using MAMP PRO, it looks like adding OAuth to PHP can now be done via checking the "OAuth" option in PHP language extensions. See: https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Languages/PHP/index.html

Not sure what version this was added, but I'm using MAMP PRO 6.4.

Answer (score 17):

After upgrading to **MAMP 2.0** for **PHP 5.2.17** I followed these steps to install the **oauth** module through pecl

1. Download [MAMP Server components and libraries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mamp/files/mamp/2.0/MAMP_components_2.0.dmg/download) Specifically you want php-5.2.17.tar.gz
2. Uncompress php-5.2.17.tar.gz to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/include/php
3. Run configure against the downloaded php. Do not build it.

   cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/include/php;
   ./configure
4. Remove broken pear config:

   mv /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/conf/pear.conf /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/conf/pear.conf.bak
5. Compile oauth

   cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin;
   ./pecl install oauth
6. Update php.ini and add extension=oauth.so This can be done in MAMP under File -> Edit Template -> PHP -> PHP 5.2.17 php.ini

Comment: This worked perfectly for me :D
You're awsome! Followed step by step. The include folder didn't exist so i created it. Moved all the contents of the php-5.2.17 folder from the dmg I downloaded to the include folder and the rest was copy/paste. Thanks!

Comment: I followed all the steps until step 3. but then terminal says: "zsh: no such file or directory: ./configure" What do I need to do?

Comment: I'm tripping up at step 5, `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/include/php/Zend/zend.h:51:11: fatal error: 'zend_config.h' file not found`

Answer (score 2):

For MAMP 3:

1. Download and install OAuth.

   ```
   sudo pecl install oauth
   ```
2. Then, go to MAMP, and click on `File > Edit Template > PHP > PHP 5.x.x php.ini` and add the following line

   ```
   extension = oauth.so
   ```

   Make sure to choose the current running php version (or press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to edit MAMP's running php.ini file).
3. Restart MAMP servers.

Answer (score 1):

Since MAMP 3.0 sources are hard to find but you can download sources from PHP.net, make sure the version match : http://php.net/downloads.php, then follow Ryan instructions.