# Trouble installing Oauth extension on MAMP PRO php version 5.3.27

Tags: php, oauth, mamp, pecl, mamp-pro

I'm following the guide here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7002008/1346932) to install the PHP OAuth extension in MAMP PRO (using version 2.2 of MAMP PRO and version 5.3.27 of PHP).

When I get to step 3 of the guide and try to run `./configure`, I get the following error:

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you are not inside the correct directory. This should work if you run these commands individually, like...

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/include/php
```

and then

```
./configure
```

This is of course assuming that you have unzipped the files into the same folder as in step 2.

Comment: I did run the commands individually as you described but that's when I get the error.